# Is 8 hours of sleep necessary?

Tags: brain, sleep

Many studies claim that humans need 8 hours of sleep. During sleep there are several different stages, from stage 1 to 4 as well as REM sleep. However, are all these stages actually necessary? If yes, what are the importance of each stage, if no, which stage(s) are/is insignificant?

Comment: Can you give some examples of sources that others can read supporting your claim that we need "8 hours"? It would definitely help strengthen your question.

Comment: It's controversial, but there are some indications for the role of different sleep stages by selective restricting these stages on volunteers of sleep studies and looking at the effects the next day. There found many different roles but broadly speaking, the best evidence is that nonREM (stage 1-4) sleep plays a role in memory consolidation (storing of new memories from the previous day) and creating "space" for new memories the following day, while REM sleep has a role in problem solving and mood calibration. The work of Matthew Walker (Berkeley) and Robert Stickgold (Harvard) is particularly

Comment: Please add references!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/43168)